# How to prevent duplicate screen session name

Tags: screen

How can I prevent screen starting if an existing session name exists?

```
screen -dmS monitor ~/monitor.app
screen -dmS monitor ~/monitor.app <- this should not start
```

Another option is to do a bash script and write PIDs etc, but could this be achieved by using screen? Thanks